# Stretches for Lifts

Tags: weightlifting, stretching

Is there a good reference that I could use to pair stretches with weight lifts? I'm never sure which stretches to use to counter any flexibility losses for a particular lift.

To give a concrete example, what stretches are a good pairing for:

- hammer dumbell curls
- incline bench press

Is there a good book for this? Website? App?

Comment: Check out athlean x on youtube. He's got videos on stretching and flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

Nike Training Club and Freeletics both include stretching as part of lifting. I think Under Armour has an app as well. I would recommend including dynamic stretching as a warmup and static stretching as a cool down. A quick google search will give you options for both.

For those in particular I would recommend overhead tricep stretch where you put your elbow above your head and use your other arm to pull it toward the opposite shoulder. Also a chest stretch where you put one arm extended against a wall and rotate your body away.